# swift 2 UIStackView addArrangedSubview in a background thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift2, uistackview

I want to build a grid of images whose items are fetched from the net thru a call to web services.

My view is made of an UIStackView (my app uses autolayout only and is not based on IB, everything is made programmatically).

The issue I face is that I want to arrange the subviews in the background thread, but of course, the process is halted with the fact the layout is changed while not in the main thread (and I cannot stick this in a main thread without stalling the app).

Anyone having smart way to do that? (not interested in answer that recommend using a tableview or collection view).

```
    for cat in categories {

        // Separator
        let line = UILine()
        explorer.addArrangedSubview(line)
        line.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        line.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(1).active = true


        let n = cat.publications.count

        // Category name and call to action
        if true {
            let sv = UIStackView()
            explorer.addArrangedSubview(sv)
            sv.axis = .Horizontal

            var
            label = UILabel()
            sv.addArrangedSubview(label)
            label.text = cat.name
            label.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            label.sizeToFit()

            if n >= explorerColumnsCount {
                label = UILabel()
                sv.addArrangedSubview(label)
                label.text = "Tout ＞"
                label.textColor = Customization.tintColor
                label.sizeToFit()
            }
        }
        // etc. including downloading remote image and adding to the stack view
```

Some comments related to my researches : 
Dispatching only addArrandedSubview doesn't solve the issue, firstly, because it create a shift in time with the rest of the program (main queue is asynchronous to the other thread, so one cannot predict when the add subview is gonna be done, and secondly, the main reason of the issue is the activation of constraints between elements. I tried to spend all constraints in an array and activate them in the main thread when le view tree is completed, but it turns the code very complicated.
My current solution is to run a second thread when the view tree is completed which is in charge to download and setup images in the view.

Comment: If you dispatch only call to `addArrangedSubview` to main queue, will it stall ui?

Comment: Stéphane, do you wait until you finished adding subviews before adding it to the main view? You should be able to build a view in the background and then add it when you finished?

Comment: "I want to arrange the subviews in the background thread" Why? Sure, retrieve the images in background thread, but you should dispatch the updating of the stack view back to the main thread.